# Angular 4 App in AWS S3 bucket causes CORS errors

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I created an Angular 4 App that I uploaded to Amazons S3 Bucket as a static website.
As a backend, I have a Spring Boot Application launched as an EC2-Instance over Elastic Beanstalk.
Now, when the Angular App tries to make a request to that backend, I get an xhr error. When I try to call the same endpoint with a REST client, everything works fine.

Do I have to set some S3 Bucket Policies?

Here's my current CORS-Configuration for S3 (but I think they only apply for incoming requests to S3, don't they?)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Here's the console output of chrome:
[image]

Comment: Is the CORS error coming when you try to load something from the S3 bucket, or when you call into a (separate) backend?

Comment: It comes when I call into a seperate backend.

Comment: Then you need to make sure you backend is sending the relevant `Access-Control` headers as well

Comment: The backend? Not the Angular App? The call is made by the App into my backend

Comment: That's right. The browser is blocking the call to the backend because the backend hasn't said other domains are allowed. The `Access-Control` headers sent by the backend are what tell the browser it will allow requests from another domain

Comment: So I set it as response header?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. You'll need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, and shold probably add `Access-Control-Allow-Methods`, and `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`

Comment: Ok, thx. I'll try

Comment: That didn't work :( Got the same error

Comment: That means that the front end is not getting those headers... If you check in the browser developer tools, can you see the headers in the response? There may be two requests (an OPTIONS request, and a POST or whatever), make sure the headers are there on both

Comment: They aren't there ... But if I call it with a REST client, they are. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you call it with a REST client it will work even without the headers, as CORS is enforced by the browser (not by rest clients). Are you sure it's there when you use a REST client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176977/discussion-between-kahuna-and-user184994).